# Mutate based on two conditions in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I have a R dataframe which can be generated from the code below

```
DF <- data.frame("Person_id" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), "Type" = c("IN","OUT","IN","ANC","IN","OUT","IN","ANC","EM","ANC"), "Name" = c("Nara","Nara","Nara","Nara","Dora","Dora","Dora","Dora","Sara","Sara"),"day_1" = c("21/1/2002","21/4/2002","21/6/2002","21/9/2002","28/1/2012","28/4/2012","28/6/2012","28/9/2012","30/06/2004","30/06/2005"),"day_2" = c("23/1/2002","21/4/2002","","","30/1/2012","28/4/2012","","28/9/2012","",""))
```

What I would like to do is create two new columns as `admit_start_date` and `admit_end_date` based on few conditions which are given below

**Rule 1**

```
  admit_start_date = day_1
  admit_end_date   = day_2 (sometimes day_2 can be NA. So refer Rule 2 below)
```

**Rule 2**

```
   if day_2 is (null or blank or na) and Type is (Out or ANC or EM) then 
         admit_end_date = day_1 
   else (if Type is IN)
         admit_end_date = day_1 + 5 (days)
```

This is what I am trying but doesn't seem to help

```
    transform_dates = function(DF){  # this function is to create 'date' columns  
  DF %>% 
    mutate(admit_start_date = day_1) %>% 
    mutate(admit_end_date = day_2) %>%
    admit_end_date = if_else(((Type == 'Out' & admit_end_date.isna() ==True|Type == 'ANC' & admit_end_date.isna() ==True|Type == 'EM' & admit_end_date.isna() ==True),day_1,day_1 + 5)
    )
}
```

As you can see, I am not sure how to check for `NA` for a newly created column and replace those `NAs` with `day_1` or `day_1 + 5(days)` based on Type column.

Can you please help?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to specify each condition separately after converting `"day"` columns to actual date objects.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('day')), as.Date, "%d/%m/%Y") %>%
  mutate(admit_start_date = day_1, 
         admit_end_date = case_when(
         !is.na(day_2) ~day_2,
         is.na(day_2) & Type %in% c('OUT', 'ANC', 'EM') ~ day_1, 
         Type == 'IN' ~ day_1 + 5))


#  Person_id Type Name      day_1      day_2 admit_start_date admit_end_date
#1          1   IN Nara 2002-01-21 2002-01-23       2002-01-21     2002-01-23
#2          1  OUT Nara 2002-04-21 2002-04-21       2002-04-21     2002-04-21
#3          1   IN Nara 2002-06-21       <NA>       2002-06-21     2002-06-26
#4          1  ANC Nara 2002-09-21       <NA>       2002-09-21     2002-09-21
#5          2   IN Dora 2012-01-28 2012-01-30       2012-01-28     2012-01-30
#6          2  OUT Dora 2012-04-28 2012-04-28       2012-04-28     2012-04-28
#7          2   IN Dora 2012-06-28       <NA>       2012-06-28     2012-07-03
#8          2  ANC Dora 2012-09-28 2012-09-28       2012-09-28     2012-09-28
#9          3   EM Sara 2004-06-30       <NA>       2004-06-30     2004-06-30
#10         3  ANC Sara 2005-06-30       <NA>       2005-06-30     2005-06-30
```

The dates in the dataframe are not of class "Date", (`class(DF$day_1)`), using `mutate_at` we change their class to "Date" so we can perform mathematical calculations on it. `starts_with('day')` means that any column whose name starts with `"day"` would be converted to "Date" class. We use `mutate_at` when we want to apply the same function to multiple columns.

`case_when` is an alternative to nested `ifelse` statements. They execute in sequential order. So first condition is checked, if the condition is satisfied it doesn't check the remaining conditions. If the first condition is not satisfied, it checks for the second condition and so on. Hence, no `else` is required here. If none of the conditions are satisfied it returns `NA`. Check `?case_when`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. But would you mind to help me understand what does `mutate_at(vars(starts_with('day')) do? In addition what does this mean `!is.na(day_2) ~day_2`?

Comment: I don't see `else keyword` for `Type == IN`?

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah - I am trying to read the code to see whether it is intutive/easy to interpret. Can you confirm when my understanding is right? Case when first checks `if day_2 is not na`, if yes, then it assigns the value to admit_end_date. 2nd condition it checks `if day_2 is na and type is any of OUT, ANC, EM`, if yes it assign day_1 which is correct. But May I know why don't you check `na condition for `Type == IN`. Shouldn't it be `is.na(day_2) & Type == IN` ~ DAY_1 + 5?

Comment: Does ~ operator indicate assign/equals to?

Comment: yes, I thought so too but in your Rule 2 you did not mention to check for `NA` when `Type == IN`. Also, yes `~` means equal to. If the condition is satisfied then assign this value.

Comment: Hi, can help me with this post?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698244/get-no-of-days-to-prev-and-next-year-using-r